# ¿Qué hace está línea de código PYTHON?

Tags: python

no termino de comprender qué hace exactamente esta línea de código:

```
    x = '{0:07b}'.format(e.x)
    y = '{0:07b}'.format(e.y)
```

El caso es que esas dos líneas me guardan una información que viene a ser una imagen, y la imagen la veo girada 180 grados, por lo que me gustaría entender qué hacen exactamente para poder guardar bien la info y ver la imagen sin ninguna rotación.

Link a la función: https://github.com/fedepare/rosbag2aedat/blob/master/rosbag2aedat.py

Gracias

Comment: Esas líneas simplemente generan una representación en binario (unos y ceros) de los valores de `x` y de `y` respectivamente, usando 7 bits y rellenando con ceros por la izquierda. Es decir, si por ejemplo `e.x` tiene el valor 5, el resultado en `x` sería la cadena `"0000101"`. No veo que tenga nada qué ver con imagenes ni con girar nada. Mirando el resto del código que enlazas veo que está montando un número binario mayor, a base de concatenar otras cadenas binarias, para después volcar los números binarios así generados como secuencias de bytes.

Comment: Aparentemente todo eso es para generar alguna secuencia de bytes específica de cierto formato, para volcarlo a disco. Se supone que el software que lea ese formato sabrá interpretarlo (y será el responsable de ese giro que mencionas, supongo)